# UIPanGestureRecognizer is moving subviews while dragging

Tags: ios, swift

So I want to add a PanGestureRecognizer to a UIView class that I have made. Everything is working well, however: when I drag the view, it's subviews are also moving/updating etc.

- -I am using SnapKit for my view's constraints
- -I tried setting translatesAutoresizingMask to false, no result
- -I tried to set constant constraints on the subviews,not result

Here is a gif of what it looks like:

https://media.giphy.com/media/oI0Wf5T6B0jIY/giphy.gif

Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Hi, the gif image URL is broken.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected and is how UIKit (and essentially all 2D/3D scene graphs) are designed to work.  The geometry of a view is relative to its parent view.  If the parent view moves, so do its decedents.

If you do not want a view to be dependent on the position of the view being moved, it probably should not be a subview of that view in the first place.  It's possible to apply the inverse movement to the subviews to make it appear that they're not moving, but that is most likely a lot more work than just not making them subviews in the first place.

Comment: I am ok with the subviews being rotated as I move and drag the Parent View, what I do not get is why the constraints are changing. For example, the bottom bar that disappears or the image that increases in size.

Comment: Hard for me to speculate what's going on there, as I'm not familiar with SnapKit.  Having said that, the frame of a view is it's bounding rectangle, so when you start to rotate something, the frame typically gets larger.  Perhaps what you're seeing is because the subviews are based on the width of the parent and not pinned to its edges?  The geometry of views gets much trickier to deal with once you're applying transforms.

Comment: Hey Charles, thanks for this. All of my subviews are on using the edges for the width, so I am not sure why this would happen.

Comment: I suspect it has to do with the frame changing during rotation.  For the sake of experimentation, you could potentially set a fixed width/height on the subviews to see if that fixes the issue.  It's going to be a matter of setting up the constraints on your subviews to not be affected by the transform on the parent.